# Parametric parallel lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

What is the distance between the parallel lines given by
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} + t \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$and $\begin{pmatrix} -5 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} + s \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$?

I understand that, for each of these lines, I can create systems of equations with the variables $t$ and $s$, respectively, but I am stuck on how to evaluate the distance between these two lines.

Help with this endeavor would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.  The second line has point $\pmatrix{-13\\0}$, when $s=2$.

A line perpendicular to the parallel lines has slope $-\dfrac34$.

Take the point we mentioned and the slope we mentioned to get the equation of a line

perpendicular to the parallel lines, and find where it intersects the first line.

Then find the distance from the point we mentioned to the point you found.

Answer (score 0):

The first line, say $L_{1}$ can be written as $y=\frac{3x}{4}+\frac{13}{4}$ and the second line $L_{2}$ is given by $y=\frac{3x}{4}+\frac{39}{4}$. If point $(x_{1},y_{1})$ lies on $L_{1}$ and point $(x_{2},y_{2})$ lies on $L_{2}$ the distance between these two points is $\sqrt{(x_{1}-x_{2})^2+(y_{1}-y_{2})^2}$.

To find the shortest distance between the two lines you have to find a line perpendicular to $L_{1}$ (or $L_{2}$) and find where this line meets $L_{2}$ (or $L_{1}$) and then apply the formula above.

Answer (score 0):

The classical way is projecting $\begin{pmatrix} -5 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix}- \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -6 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$  onto a normalized vector orthogonal to the given lines:

$$\frac{1}{5}\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -4 \end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow d= \frac{1}{5}\left\lvert \begin{pmatrix} -6 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ -4 \end{pmatrix}\right\rvert =\frac{26}{5}=5.2$$

Answer (score 0):

Pick a point $P_0$ on one of the lines and two points $P_1$ and $P_2$ on the other one. The distance between the lines is the altitude of the triangle $\triangle{P_0P_1P_2}$ from $P_0$. Using the formula $A=\frac12bh$ for the area of a triangle, you can find $h$: for this triangle we have $b=P_1P_2$, so you just need some way to compute the area of the triangle given the three vertices. One way to do that is to use a determinant: $$A=\frac12\begin{vmatrix}P_1-P_0\\P_2-P_0\end{vmatrix}.$$ The two factors of $1/2$ cancel, giving $$h = {1\over\lVert P_2-P_1\rVert}\begin{vmatrix}P_1-P_0\\P_2-P_0\end{vmatrix}.$$ (Well, really the absolute value of this expression.)

Note that since the line that we’re taking two points from is given in the parametric form $\mathbf Q+t\mathbf v$, we can take advantage of linearity of the determinant: setting $P_1=Q$ and $P_2=Q+\mathbf v$, we have $P_2-P_1=\mathbf v$ and the above determinant is $$\begin{vmatrix}Q-P_0\\Q+\mathbf v-P_0\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}Q-P_0\\\mathbf v\end{vmatrix},$$ which requires even less computation